# Hide right menu/click from embed html files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I am trying to hide the contextual menu when there is a right click event on `embed` html file.

The code I have works fine however when I right click on the embed window the menu is not hidden anymore.

How can I definitely hide the contextual menu (in certain versions of the Safari Browser Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17))?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5ruy3tx1/)

js

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
    alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);
} else {
  document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
    alert("You've tried to open context menu");
    window.event.returnValue = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: What embed window?  The code works in all scenarios, what events specifically are you saying it does not work?

Comment: I don't see any context menu when I right click. Don't see an issue

Comment: th code does not hide the right menu

Comment: on safari does not work

Comment: By the way, unless you're supporting IE8 or earlier, you don't need `attachEvent` any more...

Comment: Please specify the browser/OS version combinations on which others can reproduce the issue. Otherwise, how can anyone tell if they've fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The code should work right... as you say, it woks fine in **YOUR CODE** (not in the embedded page), depending on the method you used to embed the page, yo may (not) be able to modify it (you can't modify embedded websites for user-security issues, especially if the embedded site is in other domain) For that purpose, you may consider using a proxy.

I don't know the purpose of hiding the context menu, but if I can give you my advice, I think the effort is unnecessary as users do only sometimes right click; but when they do, they want to be able to do the common things to do when you right click (copy, search, translate, and other services)